# ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types when checking for NaN-inputs in a dataset

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm trying to do something as simple as checking the titanic dataset for NaN values in python (I know they are in the "age" column, so this is more to practice).

When using np.isnan im getting:
*TypError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''*

```
ds = sn.load_dataset("titanic")
for i in range(0,len(ds.index)):
    for j in range(0, len(ds.columns)):
        # Check if cell is NaN
        if np.isnan(ds.iloc[i][j]):
            print("it works, yay")
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Going by the documentation for `numpy.isnan`, `ufunc` docs and `numpy.can_cast`; the issue that you're currently facing is owing to the fact that `np.isnan` would not respond favorably for any datatype other than "int" & "float".
I suggest you make use of `pd.isna` which is returning desired results:

```
count = 0
ds = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
for i in range(0,len(ds.index)):
    for j in range(0, len(ds.columns)):
        # Check if cell is NaN
        if pd.isna(ds.iloc[i][j]):
            count+=1
print(count)
```

Here I replaced the print with a counter to check NaN values and it returns 869 which is in line with what we have in the dataset.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 891 entries, 0 to 890
Data columns (total 15 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype   
---  ------       --------------  -----   
 0   survived     891 non-null    int64   
 1   pclass       891 non-null    int64   
 2   sex          891 non-null    object  
 3   age          714 non-null    float64 
 4   sibsp        891 non-null    int64   
 5   parch        891 non-null    int64   
 6   fare         891 non-null    float64 
 7   embarked     889 non-null    object  
 8   class        891 non-null    category
 9   who          891 non-null    object  
 10  adult_male   891 non-null    bool    
 11  deck         203 non-null    category
 12  embark_town  889 non-null    object  
 13  alive        891 non-null    object  
 14  alone        891 non-null    bool    
dtypes: bool(2), category(2), float64(2), int64(4), object(5)
memory usage: 80.7+ KB
```